# SQL Server CE convert to SQL Server Express Website publishing strategy? Using Umbraco and getting started

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I am looking to convert from SQL Server CE to SQL Server 2012 (or 2016) for my Umbraco project, but I am unsure what the best strategy is for deployment.

I have a godaddy plesk server that runs SQL Server 2012 Express. My Umbraco project is set up with SQL Server CE, but I am looking to convert it to SQL Server Express (for performance and future growth).

My local machine is running SQL Server 2012 (sp1) Express. I am unsure what to do with respect to the conversion from CE to Express.

1. Do I upgrade my local machine to SQL Server 2016 Express, and then convert the CE to 2016 Express? I am worried that this will cause issues when I publish my website to godaddy?
2. Do I just convert SQL Server CE to SQL Server 2012, and then publish it; and forget about upgrading to 2016 Express so as to avoid compatibility issues with my godaddy plesk server (which runs 2012 express)?
3. Do I have to connect to my SQL Server 2012 on godaddy, then convert the CE to it? I would prefer to avoid this so I can develop and test locally, and then publish the local database to the server database.

Essentially, I am looking for the best practice with respect to pre-deployment and deployment.

What I've done is migrated SQL Server CE to my current SQL Server 2012 Express. I was worried that I may have compatibility issues with 2016.

Comment: If your hoster is using SQL Server **2012**, then I'd use the same version locally - makes a lot more sense than having a different version with different capabilities and running into compatibility issues all the time .... Upgrading from SQL Server 2012 to 2016 at a later point in time should be relatively easy and painless

Comment: Thanks Marc.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Per Marc's suggestion, I decided to go with option 2, and everything seems ok right now.